# NodeJS Async call inside regular callback VS callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, async.js

Are there any differences in **performance** or **memory** between these 2 ways of waiting for a database query to end and executing consequent code?
Notice that it is anyway wrapped in a regular non-async function.

***Version 1 (async / await wrapped in regular function):***

```
controller.on('message_received', function (message) {
    console.log("event:message_received, facebook_postback");
    newMessage(bot, message);
});


async function newMessage(bot, message) {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            where: { uid: message.user }
        });

       console.log('done');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

***Version 2 (without async / await):***

```
controller.on('message_received', function (message) {
    console.log("event:message_received, facebook_postback");
    newMessage(bot, message);
});


function newMessage(bot, message) {
        const user = User.findOne({
            where: { uid: message.user }
        }, function(result) {
            console.log('done');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `User.findOne` return? What are you going to do with `user`?

Comment: No, they're not equivalent in *functionality*. The one catches `await`ed rejections, the other catches only synchronous exceptions. Memory and performance are irrelevant as long as they don't do the same thing.

Comment: So `User.findOne` supports both a promise and a callback interface? There's still a difference in the return value of `newMessage`, but you don't seem to care about that - however when you do, `async`/`await` syntax will be much more reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the same, I don't think there should be any difference on performance since the `async/await` is just some `syntactic sugar` to work with promises and I haven't seen any performance issues on using `Promises` instead of `Callback` functions.

But the `async/await` version has definitely a better readability, so better to understand and work with.

Also is so easy to follow a sync flow style while it's executed in a asynchronous way.